# Re-throw exception in java catch clause

Tags: java

I am trying to log and re-throw exception in a try/catch statement in Java. When I try to throw the exception in the catch statement by adding "throw e", like code below, I get the following error:

> Unhandled exceptions: java.lang.IllegalAccessException, java.lang.InstantiationException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, java.lang.NoSuchMethodException, java.text.ParseException, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

```java
@Override
public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Object value) throws TypeConversionException {
    try {
        return FieldMappingHelper.process(type, value, this.fieldsMapperType, this.camelContext);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | ParseException e) {
            throw e;
    }
}
```

I can put the "throw e" in another catch like below but is there a cleaner way of re-throwing the class? I can't add exceptions to the method definition since this overrides a method from parent class.

```java
@Override
public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Object value) throws TypeConversionException {
    try {
        return FieldMappingHelper.process(type, value, this.fieldsMapperType, this.camelContext);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | ParseException e) {
        try {
            throw e;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException
                | ParseException | NoSuchMethodException
                | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException IllegalAccessException) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not work. I am getting compilation errors.

Comment: Does `TypeConversionException` have a constructor that takes a `Throwable`? If not, you can easily just add one, and put `super(cause)` inside it

Answer (score 1):

All those exceptions are checked exceptions, which means that you cannot (re-)throw them unless declared. Since the method already declares a `TypeConversionException` you can wrap the other exceptions as cause.

Assuming we are talking about [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/TypeConversionException.java):

```
@Override
public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> type, Object value) throws TypeConversionException {
    try {
        return FieldMappingHelper.process(type, value, this.fieldsMapperType, this.camelContext);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | ParseException e) {
            throw new TypeConversionException(value, type, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of catching exceptions is to handle them appropriately. These are checked exceptions, which *must* be handled, so if you're just going to throw them again, you should declare them in the throws clause.

That said, if you want to be lazy, you can just wrap `e` in an unchecked exception and re-throw it.

```
catch (SomeCheckedException e) {
  throw new Error(e); //or RuntimeException, either works
}
```

Lombok also has a `SneakyThrow` annotation that lets you throw checked exceptions sneakily. If you don't want to use that, the below code should work just as well:

```
public <T extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(Throwable t) throws T {
  throw (T) t;
}
```

and then

```
try {
        return FieldMappingHelper.process(type, value, this.fieldsMapperType, this.camelContext);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | ParseException e) {
            sneakyThrow(e);
    }
```

Comment: Your suggestion is very bad. An `Error` should nor bean thrown and also use the base class `RuntimeException` is bad practise

Comment: @Jens I mentioned at the top that the OP is supposed to handle it, and this is just a temporary thing if they want to be lazy and leave it until later

Comment: @user, I need to log a message to the application log and as I said at the beginning of the question, I can't add it to the method signature so I must use try/catch and re-throw the exception.

Comment: @F.K. Can you log the exception?